# How to change datetime format in Django-filter form?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-filter, django-widget

I'm creating a `filter` which contains `datetime` range choice. I would like user to be able to input date in this format: `24.08.2017 17:09`

From docs, it is possible to specify a widget (from `django.forms`) and widget has attribute `input_formats`.

So this would be a solution:

```
datetime_range = django_filters.DateTimeFromToRangeFilter(method='datetime',
                 label=u'Čas od do',widget=forms.widgets.DateTimeInput(format="%D.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

The problem is that it uses `DateTimeFromToRangeFilter` which uses two `DateTimeInput` fields. So if I specify the widget, it renders one `DateTimeInput` instead of two inputs.

So the question is, how to specify the format (without changing widget)?

I'm trying to specify `input_formats` inside `__init__(...)` but it raises:

> Exception Value:   can't set attribute

```
def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    self.base_filters['datetime_range'].field = (forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=["%D.%m.%Y %H:%M"]),forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=["%D.%m.%Y %H:%M"]))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy solution would be to simply modify the [`DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#datetime-input-formats) setting.

Alternatively, you could create a custom field, based on the existing [DateTimeRangeField](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/blob/1.0.4/django_filters/fields.py#L58-L64).

```py
class CustomDateTimeRangeField(django_filters.RangeField):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        fields = (
            forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=["%D.%m.%Y %H:%M"]),
            forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=["%D.%m.%Y %H:%M"]),
        )
        super(CustomDateTimeRangeField, self).__init__(fields, *args, **kwargs)
```

From here, you can either create a separate class, or override the `field_class` for all `DateTimeFromToRangeFilter`s.

```py
class CustomDateTimeFromToRangeFilter(django_filters.RangeFilter):
    field_class = CustomDateTimeRangeField

# or 

django_filters.DateTimeFromToRangeFilter.fields_class = CustomDateTimeRangeField
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to set this

```
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.form.fields['date__gt'].input_formats = [ '%d-%b-%Y' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using django-filter==2.0.0. I found that the Django `DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS` settings didn't seem to be honored. I essentially used the accepted answer but I found that I also needed to specify the widget attribute:

```
class ISODateTimeRangeField(django_filters.filters.RangeField):
    widget = django_filters.filters.DateTimeRangeField.widget

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        fields = (
            DateTimeField(input_formats=['%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ']),
            DateTimeField(input_formats=['%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ']),
        )
        super(ISODateTimeRangeField, self).__init__(fields, *args, **kwargs)


django_filters.DateTimeFromToRangeFilter.field_class = ISODateTimeRangeField
```