# Django filters custom date format for DateFilter

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-filter, django-filters

Can we customize date format for DateFiler in django_filters.

Right now DateFilter accepts yyyy-mm-dd. Can we change it to mm-dd-yyyy?

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/a/45641896/4151233?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah you can, try this

```
date = filters.DateFilter(field_name='date', lookup_expr='gte', input_formats=["%m-%d-%Y"])
```